# assign array of category to custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I tried to assign array of categories to custom post type on creation, so I wrote the following code:

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_name' => $title_slug,
        'post_title' => $title_slug,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'test',
        'post_author' => 'me',
        'post_excerpt' => '',
    //  'post_date' => $date,
        'post_category' => $categories_id,
    //  'tags_input' => array($tags)
    ));
    //print_r($post_categories );
    print_r($categories_id);
    wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, $categories_id) ;
```

But it doesn't work no category was affected to the custom post even if the `print_r($categories_id)` return the following array `Array ( [0] => 51 [1] => 52 [2] => 53 [3] => 54 [4] => 55 [5] => 54 )`  which is the list of category id.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the `$post_id` returning a post id? If there's a problem creating the post, that variable could also be a wp_error.

Comment: Hi, the post is created well , with the title defined , only categories are not affected to the custom post created.

Comment: Your call to `wp_set_post_categories` is unnecessary, passing `post_category` as a parameter should be enough on its own. Where is `$categories_id` coming from?

Comment: Also, does your `test` post type actually support categories? If you don't declare that it supports them, you can't add them

Comment: my post type support category , the meta box category is visible in the right of custom post edit page , and the $categories_id array is comming from list of wp_create_category('categorie_name') command

Answer (score 0):

Use the tax_input argument like this:

```
$categories = array(51,52,53,54,55);
$post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_name' => $title_slug,
        'post_title' => $title_slug,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'test',
        'post_author' => 'me',
        'post_excerpt' => '',
    //  'post_date' => $date,
        'post_category' => $categories_id,
    //  'tags_input' => array($tags),
        'tax_input' => array(
                         'category' => $categories
                       );
    ));
```

Happy Coding ;)